# Rspec: How to add an error message to is_expected to?

Tags: rspec

I am testing imported object like this:

```
%w(fields to test).each do |field|
  its(field) { is_expected.to eq original.send(field) }
end
```

How can I add an error mesage to this setup so I know which field failed? Tried to add second param to `eq` and `is_expected` by it simply fails.

Did it like this, but it's inelegant:

```
specify do
  expect(
    subject.send(field) == original.send(field)
  ).to be_truthy, field"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way (one reason I like Unit::Test over rspec), but you could add a context eg:

```
%w(fields to test).each do |field|
  context "for #{field}" do
    its(field) { is_expected.to eq original.send(field) }
  end
end
```